# update json values with json4s for a json path

Tags: scala, json4s

I want to update json values in my Json. I tried using transform field and replace methods but each has a problem which blocks me to proceed . So I am looking for some help. I have to make a method which takes a List of  Map argument , the Key in that Map Corresponds to the Json Path and the value be the value to be updated for example:

```
def jsonFieldUpdater( SeaarchKey :  List(Map(key, VALUE ) )
```

So in the map I have a Json Path like 
 [\inner\age, 30 ] which acts as a key ; my method reads it and updates that field not all the age keys. See below example

```
{"name":"luca", "id": "1q2w3e4r5t", "age": 26, "inner": { "age": 27 }, "url":"http://www.nosqlnocry.wordpress.com"}
```

I am bit stuck here as if i use Use transformfield method it updates all values which has the key as age, I dont want that I want to go to a specific path and transform it. My code block is :

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
object Json4sTest {  
  def main(arg: Array[String]) {
    //val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")
    //val lines = try source.mkString finally source.close()
    var json = parse("""{"name":"luca", "id": "1q2w3e4r5t", "age": 26, "inner": { "age": 27 }, "url":"http://    www.nosqlnocry.wordpress.com"}""")
    println(pretty(json))
    //JObject(List(JField("foo", JObject(List(JField("bar", JInt(1))))))).replace("foo" :: "bar" :: Nil, JString("baz"))
    json = json.replace("inner" :: "age" :: Nil, 29)
    json = json transformField {
    case ("name", _) => ("NAME", JString("Tuca"))
    case ("age", JInt(age)) => ("age", JInt(age+1))
    //case ("checkIn", date) => ("checkIn", JString(df.print(now.plusDays(deltaIn))))
    }
    println(pretty(json))

  }
}
```

The I came across the replace method which does the task , of replacement of a value. But then it looks like this :
    json = json.replace("inner" :: "age" :: Nil, 29)
I am not able to think how can I conform to this format, when i just receive a map which has a Json path and an value which has to be updated. Any other idea to achieve the same ?

I tried the solution by n4to4 but as i do the assignment of List of Map to a variable I get the error , for example:

```
val a = List(Map("inner/age" -> 35, "age" -> 27, "name" -> "foo"))
jsonFieldUpdater(json, a )
// error : type mismatch; found :    List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] required: List[Map[String,org.json4s.JValue]] (which expands to) List[Map[String,org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue]]
```

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have to be `List` of `Map` probably...?

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

object Json4sTest {
  def main(arg: Array[String]) {
    var json = parse("""{"name":"luca", "id": "1q2w3e4r5t", "age": 26, "inner": { "age": 27 }, "url":"http://    www.nosqlnocry.wordpress.com"}""")
    println(pretty(json))

    val a: List[Map[String, JValue]] = List(Map("inner/age" -> 35, "age" -> 27), Map("name" -> "foo"))
    val r = jsonFieldUpdater(json, a)
    println(pretty(r))

    val b = List(Updater("inner/age", 35), Updater("age", 27), Updater("name", "foo"))
    val s = jsonFieldUpdater2(json, b)
    println(pretty(s))
  }

  def jsonFieldUpdater(json: JValue, list: List[Map[String, JValue]]): JValue =
    list.foldLeft(json) { case (json, kvs) =>
      kvs.foldLeft(json) { case (json, (key, value)) =>
        json.replace(key.split("/").toList, value)
      }
    }

  case class Updater(key: String, value: JValue) {
    def path: List[String] = key.split("/").toList
  }

  def jsonFieldUpdater2(json: JValue, list: List[Updater]): JValue =
    list.foldLeft(json) { case (json, u) =>
      json.replace(u.path, u.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and looks good, but I see that if I do take a variable to store the List of Map, like :   val a = List(Map("inner/age" -> 35, "age" -> 27, "name" -> "foo"))  and then call jsonFieldUpdater(json, a) // gives me an error : "type mismatch; found : List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] required: List[Map[String,org.json4s.JValue]] (which expands to) List[Map[String,org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue]]"

Comment: You need to specify the type explicitly, or you might want to introduce a custom type (`Updater` above), which seems clearer to me.

Comment: Hi. I have successfully used your solution above for pathing values, but it fails with patching arrays.
Eg.
{
  "id": "20",
  "elements": {
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "address": "City street 2"
      },
      {
        "navn": "Jane Doe",
        "address": "City street 3"
      }
     ]
   }
 }

I tried something like this:

val a: List[Map[String, JValue]] = List(Map("elements/children[0]/address" -> "Farming way 2", "elements/children[1]/address" -> "Farming way 3"))
val r = jsonFieldUpdater(json, a)

Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code to update field

```
import org.json4s.JValue
import org.json4s.JsonAST.JObject
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val msgJson = "{\"outer\":\"before\",\"inner\": { \"age\": 1 }}"
val msgJValue: JValue = parse(msgJson)
val mergeJValue = msgJValue merge JObject(
  List(
    ("outer", JString("after")),
    ("inner", JObject(List(("age", JInt(100)))))
  )
)
println(compact(render(mergeJValue)))//{"outer":"after","inner":{"age":100}}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
json.replace(path.split("/").toList,myNewJvalue)
```